# Insert ".so" in IDLE or Pycharm

Tags: python

i just finished to install OpenCV,
The main problem is that `import cv2` works only when run from the shell. in this case:

```
$ python3 
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22)  
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> import cv2 
>>>
```

And that's fine.
If we try to import cv2 from IDLE this is what happens:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
```

This happens because idle and Pycharm to doesn't know the path of the cv2.so file.
We would like to make possible to import cv2 also from IDLE or Pycharm.

Can somebody help us?
Federico

edit

Python3.4 Shell sys.path :

```
['', '/Users/n1/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

Terminal Python3.4 sys.path :

```
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

Comment: If you really really want to, you could always palce the cv2 folder in your project. Am I wrong?

Comment: Don't do that, you lose all the benefits of pip. Can you confirm it works on a script?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly on Terminal but doesn't find any module named cv2 when launched IDLE or Pycharm

Comment: What is the value of your `sys.path` in both situations? You might need to adjust one... Possibly when invoking from the terminal, you have a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable that's left out in idle, or something similar.

Comment: @KarelKubat You can see the result of sys.path above (one run from python's shell, the other from Terminal) 
My problem is that we don't know where to put the cv2.so file, so that idle will recognise it. 
Do you have any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for late response, maybe it helps others. The way to do it is (from PyCharm menu):

```
Run > Edit Configurations...
```

When the dialog box opens, set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable with the path to your library

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok i didn't found any way to import properly `import cv2`, but if you copy the working file`cv2`(Terminal)  in the working directory of the file that you are working on, idle will recognise it.

Example:

Folder Project contains: cv2.so; try.py; test.jpg

the try.py is like this:

```
import cv2
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('hello')
capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# get frame, apply Gaussian smoothing, show result
while True:
ret,im = cap.read()
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im,(0,0),5)
cv2.imshow('camera blur',blur)
if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
    break`
```

If you run it from idle it will import the file properly.

If you know another way to import cv2 without copying it to the directory feel free to write here:)